# Why isn't Mathematica outputting the inverse fourier transform of this function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I'm brand new to Mathmematica, so please be nice. I don't understand where I'm going wrong. I just need to use the method of inverse fourier transform on this wavefunction to get the momentum-space wavefunction.

**The original wavefunction:**

[image]

**The output, which doesn't seem right**

[image]

**The code:**

```
InverseFourierTransform[(m*w/(Pi*\[HBar]))^(1/4) E^(-m*w*x^2/(2*\[HBar])) E^(-I*w*t/2), x, t]
```

Comment: 'Pi' versus 'pi' and'E' versus 'e' and 'I' versus 'i'. All built-in names start with a capital.

Comment: Ok I fixed that but it still gives me the same output as the image above.

Comment: Then enter code in code blocks vice images so people can can work with it and correct/edit your question.

Comment: @BobHanlon Done. Good idea, I don't know why I didn't do that initially. I normally do that on SO.

Comment: Why are the transform and original variables both present in your wavefunction?

Comment: This is the wavefunction for the ground state of the harmonic oscillator. Other than that, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you should go from x-space to p-space. x- to t does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

J.M.' s comment related to both `w` and `t` appearing in the expression to be transformed. Assuming that the `t` in `E^(-I*w*t/2)` was actually meant to be an `x` then

```
InverseFourierTransform[(m*w/(Pi*ℏ))^(1/4) E^(-m*w*
     x^2/(2*ℏ)) E^(-I*w*x/2), w, t]

(*  (((m/ℏ)^(1/4)*
           (-((x*(m*x + I*ℏ))/ℏ))^
             (1/4) - (-(m/ℏ))^(1/4)*
           ((x*(m*x + I*ℏ))/ℏ)^(1/4))*
      ℏ*Gamma[1/4]*
      (Abs[t]*Cos[(5/4)*ArcTan[
                 (2*t*ℏ)/(m*x^2 + 
                      I*x*ℏ)]] - 
         I*t*Sin[(5/4)*ArcTan[
                 (2*ℏ*Abs[t])/(m*x^2 + 
                      I*x*ℏ)]]))/
   (2*2^(1/4)*Pi^(3/4)*x*
      (m*x + I*ℏ)*
      ((x^2*((-I)*m*x + ℏ)^2)/ℏ^2)^
        (1/4)*(1 + (4*t^2*ℏ^2)/
             (x^2*(m*x + I*ℏ)^2))^(5/8)*
      Abs[t])  *)
```

Assumptions on any of the parameters might simplify this.